# How to place hyperlink to a website on android app?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to place a hyperlink on android app that I am developing.

I tried this:

**main.xml**

```
<TextView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:text="@string/hyperlink"
android:id="@+id/hyperlink" 
android:autoLink="web"
>
</TextView>
```

**The strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">WebLink</string>
<string name="hyperlink">http://google.com</string>
</resources>
```

But the problem is, the link looks like this: http://google.com and I don't want to show the actual url.

**1)** How to replace link by text like "Click Here to visit Google" and the text is linked with the website url ?

**2)** How to place email address (same question, how to replace it with text something like "Click Here to Email" and the text should be linked with [email@domain.com](http://email@domain.com))

---

I also tried this tutorial: http://coderzheaven.com/2011/05/10/textview-with-link-in-android/

But I am getting following error messages:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
http cannot be resolved to a variable   MyLink.java /MyLink/src/com/MyLink  line 21 Java Problem
Syntax error on token "" <br /> <a href="", ? expected after this token MyLink.java /MyLink/src/com/MyLink  line 21 Java Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to boolean    MyLink.java /MyLink/src/com/MyLink  line 20 Java Problem
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the default [Linkify class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html).

Here is an [Example](http://jtomlinson.blogspot.com/2010/03/textview-and-html.html) and the code from the tutorial:

This is my sample code for you, I think this will solve your problem:

```
    public class StackOverflowActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // 1) How to replace link by text like "Click Here to visit Google" and
        // the text is linked with the website url ?
        TextView link = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String linkText = "Visit the <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>StackOverflow</a> web page.";
        link.setText(Html.fromHtml(linkText));
        link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        // 2) How to place email address
        TextView email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        String emailText = "Send email: <a href=\"mailto:person@stackoverflow.com\">Click Me!</a>";
        email.setText(Html.fromHtml(emailText));
        email.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
}
```

Comment: how about this tutorial (i am trying to make it work but I am getting error messages: [http://coderzheaven.com/2011/05/10/textview-with-link-in-android/](http://coderzheaven.com/2011/05/10/textview-with-link-in-android/) - Please see above, I updated my post.

Comment: I don't see your java code, so I don't know what is the problem. In my opinion you need to change the " " to ' '. I attached a working sample code above, try this code.

Comment: For those reading more recently, API 24 saw the deprecation of Html.fromHtml(string source). Instead, use Html.fromHtml(string source, int flags) with flag FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY. See the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

Answer (score 0):

here is a basic example of placing hyperlink on android app which user directed to google.com

string.xml file:

```
 <string name="hyperlink"><a href="https://www.google.com/">click</a></string>
```

Textview in activity_main.xml:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textviewHyperlink"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hyperlink"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

MainActivity.java file:

```
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textviewHyperlink);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

here is the how it is will be looking like:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBt3U.png)

Note: Be sure that implement this in MainActivity.java:

```
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
```